# Covariance Matrix that doesnt have the Oracle Property Condition (adaptive lasso)

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, covariance-matrix

I am studying the paper about the adaptive lasso from Zou (2004): In particular I have a question regarding to Corollary 1 in the paper.
[image]

What whould be a numerical example for such a matrix ?

The 2nd Question is maybe a bit off-topic, but how could I generate such an example in R?